# Dual of space of $\alpha$-densities on a vector space naturally isomorphism to $(-\alpha)$-densities

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces, line-bundles

> Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space. For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, we define $\Omega^\alpha V$, the space of $\alpha$-densities on $V$, as the set of all maps $\omega : V^n \to \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy $$\omega(Tv_1, \cdots, Tv_n) = |\det(T)|^{\alpha} \omega(v_1, \cdots, v_n), $$ for every $v_1, \cdots, v_n \in V$ and for every invertible linear operator $T : V \to V$.

It is clear that this space is $1$-dimensional real vector space, as if we have a basis $e_1, \cdots, e_n$ of $V$, then $\Omega^\alpha V$ is spanned by $|\varepsilon^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \varepsilon^n|^\alpha$, where $\varepsilon^1, \cdots, \varepsilon^n$ is the dual basis.

My question is the following: how can we prove that $(\Omega^\alpha V)^* \simeq \Omega^{-\alpha}V$ is a "natural" way, i.e. by constructing a map without firstly choosing a basis for $V$. I do not know how to prove this statement, as I cannot think of any linear functional on $\Omega^\alpha V$ besides the constant functional.

This question arises when considering distributions on a manifold. Another "natural" isomorphism is, for instance, $$\Omega^\alpha V \otimes \Omega^\beta V \simeq \Omega^{\alpha + \beta} V$$ via the map $\omega \otimes \eta \mapsto \omega \cdot \eta$.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. It's not clear to me how to describe things without choosing a basis first, but it is easy to show that the isomorphism is basis-independent. The bilinear map $$\Omega^\alpha V \otimes \Omega^{-\alpha}V \ni \omega\otimes \eta \mapsto \omega(e_1,\ldots, e_n)\eta(e_1,\ldots, e_n) \in \Bbb R$$is non-degenerate. If $(\widetilde{e}_1,\ldots,\widetilde{e}_n)$ is a second basis, let $T\in {\rm GL}(V)$ be defined by $Te_i = \widetilde{e}_i$, so that $|\det T|^\alpha$ cancels with $|\det T|^{-\alpha}$.

Comment: @IvoTerek I am not sure if this is the isomorphism I am looking for. The question I am asking arises in the following context: the "delta distribution at a point $p$" on a manifold is a smooth section of the bundle $\Omega^\alpha M \otimes \left(\Omega^{\alpha} M \right)^*$ over $M$, and we would like to identify this bundle  in a natural way with the bundle $M \times \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But actually, I think your idea gives us the following "natural" isomorphism: $\Omega^\alpha V \otimes \Omega^{-\alpha} V \simeq \Omega^0 V$ in a natural way via the map I wrote in the post. Then, observe that $\Omega^0 V$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, as all $0$-densities are constant. However, at the same time, $\Omega^\alpha V \otimes \left(\Omega^\alpha V \right)^* \simeq \mathrm{Hom}(\Omega^\alpha V, \Omega^\alpha V)$ in a natural way, and this latter one is again naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$, via the identity operator being mapped to $1$. Is this "natural" overall?

Comment: But how can we use this isomorphisms to conclude the question?